# PHP Regex preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace this URI

```
http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0&brand=Sony&toto=titi
```

by this URI

```
http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0&kljklj=sdfsd
```

==> I want to delete "&brand=Sony"

I tried this :

```
preg_replace('/(^.*)(&brand=.*)(&.*)/', '$1$3', 'http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0&brand=Sony&toto=titi');
```

but it doesn't work in a specific case : the case where the parameter "toto" in the URI doesn't exist

So if I do

```
preg_replace('/(^.*)(&brand=.*)(&.*)/', '$1$3', 'http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0&brand=Sony');
```

It doesn't work ==> "&brand=Sony" still appear

So how can I do ?

Comment: You aren't assigning the result of `preg_replace` to anything, so it is basically lost after its execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody. So here is my final solution and it works fine :

```
<?php
$actual_link = 'index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //complete link of my page
$parsedURL= parse_url($actual_link);
parse_str($parsedURL["query"],$tabParametersQuery);    
$tabParametersQuery['brand']="";
$newURL = "index.php?".http_build_query($tabParametersQuery);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't use regular expressions.

First, use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the url into its bits and pieces.
Then, use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on the query portion.

Do whatever you want to the query keys, then combine it all back.
To build the query string back: [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
Then build the url using [http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_replace("/\&brand=Sony/", "", $uri);
```

Comment: This is not good if brand is the first parameter after ? and not &.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace('/[\?&]brand=\w*/', '', $url);
```

Comment: that is if you want to remove any brand. If you only want to remove Sony, then suspectus's answer is correct.

Comment: This is not a good solution if the brand value contain character which is not a word - like # or something else. the solution for it is any character which is not the next param & -> [^&]+ like my solution :) peace

Comment: Good point. You should check for '&' or '?' too. But really we're both wrong, and misplacedme is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of key brand

```
preg_replace('/&?brand=[^&]+/i','',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(^.*)(&brand=.*)(&.*)?
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is just the original regexp with a question mark at the end, which does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add ?:

```
(^.*)(&brand=.*)(&.*)?

echo preg_replace(
'/(^.*)(&brand=.*)(&.*)?/', 
'$1$3', 
'http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0&brand=Sony');
```

output:

```
http://localhost/prixou/index.php?page=list&category=1&sub=1&subsub=0
```